# How to mock a method that returns `Mono<Void>`

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

How to mock a method that returns `Mono<Void>`?

I have this method that returns `Mono<Void>`

```java
public Mono<Void> deleteMethod(Post post) {

        return statusRepository.delete(post);
    }
```

In my test class I want to do something like this

```java
given(statusRepository.delete(any(Post.class))).willReturn(Mono.empty());
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you facing any specific issues?

Comment: No, Initially I got a null mono error I thought Mono.empty() was causing the error, but something else was the reason for null mono. Now, I just wanted to make sure what I was doing is correct.

Comment: As option you can use PublisherProbe<Void> probe = PublisherProbe.empty(); probe. mono(); Example from https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#testing

Comment: Post your test cases so that we can take a closer look and suggest improvements

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is possible using `Mockito.when`:

```
Mockito.when(statusRepository.delete(any(Post.class)).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
```

...call the method and verify...

```
Mockito.verify(statusRepository).delete(any(Post.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this when I don't want to have an empty mono as result.

```
when(statusRepository.delete(any(Post.class))).thenReturn(Mono.just("").then());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to do this without using `Mono.empty` so the reactive chain would complete by creating a mock object of type void. Below is a code example (written in Kotlin and using mockito-kotlin, but should be applicable to mockito as well):

```
val mockVoid: Void = mock()

whenever(statusRepository.delete(any(Post::class.java)).thenReturn(mockVoid)
```